# Calculating de facto speed based on slope

Tags: classical-mechanics, speed

I am studying from [this video](https://youtu.be/kpk2tdsPh0A?t=14m6s) and I am having trouble seeing how the de facto speed is actually calculated in the graphic at time 14:06.

In particular I don't understand how the syncing speed is computed in advance.

Please help!

Comment: It would be useful if you could rewrite your question so it is self-contained, and also explicitly explain some of the language (such as * de facto * speed, which is not standard physics nomenclature) used in the video as it is specialized to a specific video game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question really should be rewritten to be more self-contained and explained as ZeroTheHero advises. Luckily for you, there are users here who love both physics *and* video games.

What is shown as the "de facto speed" in the video is actually the horizontal $X$-axis component of the 3-d universe grid of Mario's *velocity* in space. Basically, it is the projection of Mario's velocity onto the $X$-axis and this projection's value decreases as a function of the slope until it reaches $90°$. Effectively, this is a dot product and the fact that the green arrow in the video decreased with an increase in slope is intuitive especially when you consider the cosine function's graph.[image]

I have also illustrated a mathematical interpretation of the speeds here

[image]

For him to perform the Hyper Speed Walking, he needs enough horizontal speed (in the video this is called the "de facto QPU" speed) to overbound into other PUs, **that's** why he says "It's not sufficient to have QPU speed" at 14:34. The calculation of the syncing speed is a simple matter of knowing the slope he's building speed on, i.e. the gradient of the submerged part of the slope he's walking "uphill" on and building speed backwards.